# MySQL - Retrieve last update per day per user

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a hypothetical table "users" with the columns

- user_id (auto incremented)
- name
- foo
- bar
- last_updated

This table is updated multiple times per day. How can I query to get the last update, per user, per day, going back X days?

Example Data

```
1 John a b "2013-01-31 02:01:12"
2 Rich c d "2013-01-31 22:41:12"
3 John e f "2013-01-31 22:01:15"
4 Rich g h "2013-02-01 16:01:12"
5 John i j "2013-02-01 22:21:12"
6 Rich k m "2013-02-01 22:21:12"
```

Desired Return Set:

```
2 Rich c d 2013-01-31
3 John e f 2013-01-31
5 John i j 2013-02-01
6 Rich k m 2013-02-01
```

I am able to get the last updated per user overall with the following query, it's applying it to each day that I am struggling with.

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM users u1 
    LEFT JOIN users u2
    ON (u1.name = u2.name AND u1.user_id < u2.user_id)
WHERE u2.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the table name `users` is very confusing, since these aren't the users but the logins.

Beyond that you're on the right way. You just need to add a comparison on the date in the join.

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM users u1
    LEFT JOIN users u2
    ON (u1.name = u2.name AND date_format(u1.last_updated, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(u2.last_updated, '%Y-%m-%d') AND u1.user_id < u2.user_id)
WHERE u2.user_id IS NULL
```

See it work in this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1b1a/8).

Comment: @dtcarls Please take a look.

Comment: this an ultra-scrubbed version of the table so table and column names are changed, but thank you fora more efficient version of the query. It appear I was close, I just couldn't make that last join correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do this by summarizing the data at the date level and then joining back:

```
select u.*
from users u join
     (select u.nanme, DATE(last_updated) as thedate, MAX(last_updated) as maxlastupdated
      from users u
      group by u.name, DATE(last_updated)
     ) usum
     on u.name = usum.name and
        u.last_updated = usum.maxlastupdated
```

Comment: Using a subquery works, but is slow. @dtcarls your initial query is better.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels . . . It is rather odd to say that the original query is better.  That query does not produce the desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff He only needed to add comparison on the day to the join. For the rest the query is fine. Have a look at how it works :)